# Could not Read from resource, Poll error, while reading device from V4l2src?

Tags: device, gstreamer, v4l2

I have a pipeline,

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! xvimagesink
```

It is working fine, but sometimes if the above pipeline doesn't exited properly, then if i read the device again, then facing below error.

```
Could not read from resource.. gstv4l2bufferpool.c(1023): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll (): /GstPipeline:Video-Ingestor/GstV4l2Src:CamSource:
poll error 1: Invalid argument (22).
```

In order to read again, i need to remove the device and reconnect it. Then only i can able to read it.

Is there any other way, such that whenever this error comes, read the device without removing the it?

Comment: You could try adding the `--eos-on-shutdown` option to gst-launch and see if that leads to a cleaner shutdown of the v4l2src element.

Comment: how can i enable this in a c code?

Comment: You'd be using `sigaction()` and listening for the SIGTERM and/or SIGKILL and then ending your pipeline gracefully.

Comment: i handled the sigaction in my c code. But if i manually crash the process, then at that instance sigaction will not call. At this time if i try to read the device again, i am facing above error and some times resource busy also.

Comment: You may want to paste your signal handling code and more details about how you are crashing the process.